# O que estou fazendo errado ao usar o LET (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estou usando retrofit e no onReaponse, quando tento pegar a informação do body com o (Let), o código interno não é executado.

```
response?.body()?.let {
  Log.i("Info", "Cidades: " + it.size)
}
```

Se tentar assim, também não funciona:

```
response?.body()?.let {
  Log.i("Info", "Cidades: " + it.size)
}
```

Mas se eu colocar assim, funciona:

```
if (response != null) {
  if (response.body() != null){
     Log.i("Info", "Cidades: " + response.body()?.size)
  }
}
```

O que estou perdendo? O código todo está abaixo.

```
call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Cidade>?> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Cidade>?>?, response: Response<List<Cidade>?>?) {
        /*Not working - Does Not execute Log*/
        response?.let {
            Log.i("Info", "Cidades: " + it.body()?.size)
        }

        /*Working - Does execute Log*/
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.body() != null){
                Log.i("Info", "Cidades: " + response.body()?.size)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Cidade>?>?, t: Throwable?) {
        var error = t?.message.toString()
        Log.e("error", error)

        txtErrorMessage.text = error
        txtErrorMessage.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
})
```

Comment: Aqui o `let` das duas formas funcionou como esperado. Uma dica: seu `if` pode ser simplificado da seguinte forma: `if (response?.body() != null) {`.